# Grammar of "a less nice hangout"

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

None of these (cons of a coffee shop listed above) made it a less nice hangout.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it Gramatically right? Your question has a missing. It doesn't sense :-)

Comment: If you are asking about "Does the sentence Grammatically right?", no.  If you are asking about "None of these made it a less nice hangout", what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Is the question mark (‘‘?’’) part of the sentence you’re asking about?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian got it fixed. you are very bad!LOL

Comment: @HotLicks, I don't know. less nice sounds weird and I'd like to rephrase it.

Comment: None of these (cons listed above) would keep me away from this great hangout.

Comment: It’s fine. Nice is a very flexible adjective.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, its just easier to say 'worse' - 'less nice' is clunky. Perhaps restructuring the sentence would give it greater flow? For eg. "Neither the __________ nor the _______ worsened the hangout", or "None of these made it a worse hangout".

Additionally, you may want to refine your adjectives - nice can be a bit bland - try something more relevant to the subject - cozy, comfortable, pleasant, etc.

Comment: The problem is that "worse" implies that the starting point was "bad".  If the starting point was "nice" then "worse" gives the wrong implication.

Comment: @HotLicks, what word would you suggest here?

Comment: @Fin, thanks. Do you think "worse" is still applicable given that the place was good overall.

Comment: Its difficult because there really isn't a nicer word. If I was reading this in context I don't think I'd mind, but I understand the point brought up by @HotLicks. Personally I'd say _____ didn't degrade/ruin the hangout because they don't have that initial negative connotation

Comment: @Fin, your sentence sounds great. Thanks a lot!